# GPS sentence: GPRMA

Tags: gps, nmea

I'm writting a NMEA sentences parser, and couldn't find ant documentation about GPRMA sentence except that it is: "Recommended minimum specific Loran-C data". does anyone know what is the meaning of this sentence?
does the longitude and latitude in it refer to the gps device current location?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very handy guide at http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rma:

```
eg. $GPRMA,A,llll.ll,N,lllll.ll,W,,,ss.s,ccc,vv.v,W*hh
1    = Data status 
2    = Latitude
3    = N/S
4    = longitude
5    = W/E
6    = not used
7    = not used
8    = Speed over ground in knots
9    = Course over ground
10   = Variation
11   = Direction of variation E/W
12   = Checksum
```

Now, LORAN data is **not GPS**.  It is similar, but an [old standard of ground stations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) that were used to find positions.  So to specifically answer your question, no, this is not GPS data.  If you want GPS data, you will need `$GPRMC`.

Comment: can I recieve from my gps device a 'GPRMA' sentence? and if so, do the  Latitude and longitude data in it, represent the current location?

Comment: No, LORAN is not GPS, so no, this sentence does not represent data from a GPS.  Yes, the latitude and longitude in this sentence contain the current location.